# Writing unit tests which depends on other functions in same class

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit

I have to write some unit tests which depends on other unit tests. For an example, there is a function to move files: `move_file()`. To test that function, first I'm required to create a file using the function `save_file()` which involves  another method in the same class. Calling `save_file` function involves calling a cpanel UAPI which involves some authentication. So, calling `save_file` function is essential to create a file. Is it acceptable to write a unittest to `move_file()` method using `save_file()` method to create a file?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are calling the cpanel UAPI from your class, so your tests are integration tests, really. Does that make a difference? Of course.

Generally speaking, in order to test something, you have to set up your system in a meaningful way. How to do this depends on what you are testing.

In unit tests, you're testing the subject in isolation. If it depends on something external, like an API, it's best to create an abstraction or a thin wrapper for it. That's something that you can easily mock or fake in your tests.

But even this abstraction or wrapper has to be tested with the real thing at some point. And that's when you can't fake it any more. You can't move a file that does not exist. Given that, it's perfectly acceptable to call another method to bring your test scenario into the right state.